# How to integrate upload image plugin of CKEditor in Angular Project

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to add the "Choose file option" inside CKEditor. For that, I am referring to this documentation on [Upload image plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage)

[image]

When clicking on this image icon, the below window opens up

[image]

There is no upload image option (choose file option). I want to add this plugin along with CKEditor.
Is there any way to add this using npm ?

Or is there any other way I can include this feature in CKEditor 4?

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images

Comment: @yogendarji I have gone through this documentation, but I am not able to get how can I add this Upload image plugin in my CKEditor or how can I integrate ckfinder with ckeditor. I am not able to find any npm command for installing this plugin.

Comment: you need to integrate file manager as well https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/fileupload.html#  Check sample if it helps you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ckeditor4-angular-extraplugins-7q6csv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Also this https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/166#issuecomment-774126906

Comment: @yogendarji thanks for the links. For integrating file manager, I hv to install ckfinder first ?  But I tried to find some npm install commands for ckfinder, but I am not able to find that. Can you please tell how can I install ckfinder ?

Comment: I guess it will be on backend, You don't need it on Angular. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here sharing same above if someone looking for it.

1. Set `extraPlugins: 'uploadimage'` config options.
2. Set up through the `config.filebrowserBrowseUrl` and `config.filebrowserUploadUrl configuration` settings.
3. Setup `ckfinder` as per [Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration.html)

Here is sample [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ckeditor4-angular-extraplugins-7q6csv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Main part is

```
this.ckeConfig = {
      extraPlugins: 'uploadimage',
      uploadUrl:      'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',

      // Configure your file manager integration. This example uses CKFinder 3 for PHP.
      filebrowserBrowseUrl:'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/ckfinder.html',
      filebrowserImageBrowseUrl:'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
      filebrowserUploadUrl:'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
      filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
    };
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Just 1 thing more, when selecting the image from choose file option, I am getting **Image source URL is missing.** error. Can you please tell me what is the reason of this ?

Comment: @ESCoder Fixed now, It was URL issue, Check same demo again

Comment: @ESCoder Did you click on "send it to server", after upoad?

Comment: I am able to add the images using CKEditor. But, like right now the image is getting uploaded to the CKEditor server, is there any way that images are uploaded to my own server?

Comment: You need to setup ckfinder in your local, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/quickstart.html